# Simplify a query Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

please see the code below. It works perfectly fine. However, please imagine there are up to hundreds of different case Ids (her only caseId 1 and 2). I cannot write a separate query for every single case Id. Is there a way to simplify it? I have been searching for days now..

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///running_to_csv.csv" AS row
WITH toInteger(row.case_id) AS cid, row
CREATE (event: Event {caseId: cid, activityName: row.activity, time: row.timestamp})

MATCH(event: Event)
WHERE event.caseId = 1
WITH event ORDER BY event.time ASC 
WITH apoc.coll.frequencies(apoc.coll.pairsMin(COLLECT(event.activityName))) AS g
UNWIND g AS p
RETURN*

MATCH(event: Event)
WHERE event.caseId = 2
WITH event ORDER BY event.time ASC 
WITH apoc.coll.frequencies(apoc.coll.pairsMin(COLLECT(event.activityName))) AS g
UNWIND g AS p
RETURN*
```

If you simply leave out the "event.caseId = ..." line the results are false, as the order is then oriented towards time and not caseId. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to `COLLECT` all `DISTINCT` `event.caseId` and then `UNWIND` the list for your `apoc...` processing?

Comment: It is not working no but thanks. I have the feeling that if I order on caseId and then on time, always the order of caseId is lost. In the end everything is ordered by time. But I need it to be ordered by time per case Id. Just as the individual queries do, they work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this should work, just order, then collect by the caseId, and do another ordering by caseId after you've got your frequencies by caseId but before the UNWIND:

```
MATCH(event: Event)
WITH event.caseId as caseId, event 
ORDER BY event.time ASC 
WITH caseId, collect(event.activityName) as names
WITH caseId, apoc.coll.frequencies(apoc.coll.pairsMin(names)) AS g
ORDER BY caseId ASC
UNWIND g AS p
RETURN *
```